# Calling an arrayList from another class which is private

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, actionevent

I am trying to display an arraylist in a gui. However I am getting some troubles. I need to check if my game is legal, if it is not legal then it calls getProblems which displays the arraylist. I tried to call getProblems directly in the GUI class however it will show the array as empty. (Since it's not checking if it's legal). I also tried to call isLegal then getProblems but you cannot do this in a `JOptionPane`. Any tips on how I can call it accross?

GetProblems class

```
 protected List < String > getProblems() {
     return displayOutput;
 }
```

IsLegal Class

```
public boolean isLegal() {
  boolean legality;

  if (checkRowConstraints().isEmpty()) {
    legality = true;

  } else {
    getProblems();
    legality = false;

  }
  return legalCheck;
}
```

GUI:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (!(puzzle.isLegal())) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FutoshikiFrame.this,
         puzzle.getProblems(),
         "You made a mistake!",
         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Here is difference between Actual display of GUI result and result i'm trying to get.

[image: Actual display of GUI to result and result i'm trying to get]

> Further Problem found:
>   I need to return the arraylist then empty it.  Fixed

Comment: I'm surprised that even compiles, because you are attempting to return a `String` when you've specified your return type as `List<String>` in `getProblems()`.

Comment: @TEK Adjusted, when I pasted my code into stackoverflow i forgot to remove that top line (Was formatting the array so it just prints the characters inside the square brackets only, eg: "Hi" Instead of "[Hi]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, there is an implicit call to the `List`'s `toString()` method when you call `puzzle.getProblems()` within the `JOptionPane`. So rather than get the contents of the `List`, which is what you want, you're getting whatever `toString()` is giving you.

You're not going to get the contents of the `List` unless you iterate over it first.

You could try something like this. (Note, this is untested code. For demo purposes.)

```
String formattedString = "";
//let's iterate over our List and build a formatted string for output
for(String element : puzzle.getProblems())
{
    formattedString += element;
}
```

Then you can output this formatted `String`

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (!(puzzle.isLegal())) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FutoshikiFrame.this,
         formattedString,
         "You made a mistake!",
         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```